# Is there some ways to avoid this kind of duplicated code in clojure?

Tags: clojure

I got some parameters and then call a function which accept a map of parameters.
The key's names of the map are the params' names,like this:

```
   (GET "/api/search" [nick_name gender phone max_age min_age page lmt ]
        (db-search-users :nick_name nick_name :gender gender :phone phone
:max_age max_age :min_age min_age :page page :lmt lmt))
```

is there some way to avoid the copy and paste?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I take it you're using Compojure? You're not required to destructure the parameters map (vectors in Compojure are shorthand for `{:keys [...]}`-like destructuring on the parameters map), you can simply pass it on to your function:

```
;; you can use a map to destructure the entire request map
(GET "/api/search" {:keys [params]}
  (db-search-users (select-keys params [:nick_name ...])))
```

`select-keys` is optional, although without it your function may end up receiving unexpected keys in the map.

You might want to consider validating `params` -- possibly coercing some of the values to more useful types -- before passing them on to `db-search-users`. See Prismatic's [schema](https://github.com/Prismatic/schema) for a nice way to do this.

Comment: This is really what I want.

Answer (score 2):

Let a macro do the work for you:

```
(defmacro make-get [path & keywords]
  `(GET ~path [~@keywords]
        (db-search-users ~@(flatten (map #(list (keyword %) %) keywords)))))
```

Usage:

```
(macroexpand-1 '(make-get "/api/search" nick_name gender phone max_age min_age page lmt))
(user/GET "/api/search" [nick_name gender phone max_age min_age page lmt] (user/db-search-users :nick_name nick_name :gender gender :phone phone :max_age max_age :min_age min_age :page page :lmt lmt))
```

Comment: `(defmacro make-get [path & keywords] \`(GET ~path [~@keywords] (db-search-users ~@(mapcat (juxt keyword identity) keywords))))`

Comment: is there away to write a macro that can tranform keywords to a map? This macro is good for the question.But can't be use in other functions ,because "db-search-users" is in it.

Comment: @user2219372 ... make the function-form an argument to the macro: *(defn make-get [f path & keywords] `(GET ~path [~@keywords] (~f ~@(mapcat (juxt keyword identity) keywords))))*